# How to calculate driving distance between two given LatLng points?

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-maps-api-2

I need to calculate the driving distance between two points when latitude and longitude are given (not address)!
How can I?

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAA7j_Q-rshuWkc8HyFI4V2HxQYPm-xtd00hTQOC0OXpAMO40FHAxT29dNBGfxqMPq5zwdeiDSHEPL89A" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder, location1, location2, gDir;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    gDir = new GDirections();
     location1 = {lat: '27.68389267163743', lon: '85.30214309692383', address: 'Sanepa'};


                    location2 = {lat: '27.674581642945725', lon: '85.32673358917236', address: 'Patan'};
                    gDir.load('from: ' + (location1.lat + ", " + location1.lon) + ' to: ' + (location2.lat + ", " + location2.lon));




    GEvent.addListener(gDir, "load", function() {

        var drivingDistanceKilometers = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
        alert("Distance is" + drivingDistanceKilometers); 
    });
}

function showLocation() {





}

</script>
```

It works when i pass the address as parameters in gDir.load() function but now i need to calculate only from latitude and longitude. Please help.

Comment: By reading the very descriptive and straightforward API documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService

Comment: Note: API v2 has been deprecated (for quite some time). Do not use it. It could literally stop functioning at any moment.

Comment: Reiterating what @Adam says, please convert all this from v2 to v3.  There's a very useful guide to how to do that here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use API v2 as it has been deprecated for quite some time and could literally stop functioning at any moment.

If you absolutely must use it, the way to do accomplish what you want is by using the `loadFromWaypoints` method:

```
gDir.loadFromWaypoints([(new GLatLng(lat,lng)),(new GLatLng(lat,lng))]);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GDirections.loadFromWaypoints